# SAS Proc Report Subgroup

Tags: sas, report

Let say that I Have a simple table that have four variables (Company, Profit_January, Profit_February, Profit_March).

I would like to display my report to be like this:

[image]

In which, the Profit_January, Profit_February, and Profit_March is under subgroup Profit. Is it achievable doing Proc Report?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is achievable. On the COLUMN statement, doing like so will give you the expected results:

```
PROC REPORT  DATA=mydata  NOWINDOWS;
  COLUMN Company ("Profit" Profit_January Profit_February Profit_March);
  DEFINE Company / <...> ;
  DEFINE Profit_January / DISPLAY "January" ;
  DEFINE Profit_February / DISPLAY "February" ;
  <etc.>
RUN;
```